# Cannot access android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner on fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

This happens when i extend from an **abstract base fragment** like so:

```
public abstract class BaseFragment<T extends BasePresenter, E extends BaseModel> extends Fragment {
....
}
```

, but the app still build without any errors. below is my `build.gradle` config:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig
    {
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
    } 
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you are extending the Fragment from the support library ?

Comment: Even I am getting same error. Because of which I am unable to test my presenter classes

Comment: I am trying to create a utility class using this observer. I am receiving the same issue even when passing in the Activity as a parameter to my function. This only seems to work if you use in an Activity.

Answer (score 4):

Add following line to gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1:**

> LifecycleOwner : A class that has an Android lifecycle. These events can be used by
>   custom components to handle lifecycle changes without implementing any
>   code inside the Activity or the Fragment.

To access LifecycleOwner class add following dependency in your app **build.gradle** file.

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
```

**Solution 2:**

Add following support compat dependency in your app **build.gradle** file.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Why in solution-1 we need to add that dependency, and why adding it will solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue , adding this to the apps build.gradle  might fix the issue

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and I resolved this issue by updating android support libraries in build.gradle file.

I would recommend updating your android support libraries to 27.1.1 or newer. No need to add this :

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'  (not recommended)
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps and problem will be solved:

1. If the following dependency is not added in your app level's build.gradle then add it:

   ***implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"*** 
   and sync the project with 
   gradle files.
2. If it is already added then:

   a. Go to **Tools**-> **Clean Project**

   b. **Rebuild Project**

   c. Go to **File**-> **Invalidate Caches and Restart**

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just updated mine to ff versions and the error disappeared

> ```
> implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
> implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.3.0-alpha03'
> ```